# Android Google Maps in center of screen bounces while zooming

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a Google Maps Android app with markers. My problem is that a marker centered in the middle of the screen doesn't stay put when zooming. It's a little hard to explain so here is a video:
https://vimeo.com/202160109
I am using google play services 10.0.1. My first thought that this was a lib bug having to do with a transparent system bar, but the same issue happens even with `fitsystemwindows="true"`.

What can I do to have a marker stay in the center of the screen when zooming?

Comment: Thanks for the video. At a look, it might have something to do with attempting to reposition the two markers (the cross and the tent) so they're adjacent without colliding. Is there code surrounding that?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the cross is not part of the map, it's a completely separate View that's drawn on top of the MapView. (It's a center of the map, I realize it is offset from the center which is a bit confusing, but it does not interact with the tent map marker at all.)

Comment: Are the `LatLng` of the `Marker` and the `LatLng` of the camera position exactly the same?

Comment: Yes, the `LatLng` of the `Marker` is fixed as is the camera (except the zoom). I just tried it with play services 10.0.0 and still seeing this issue. I am leaning towards this being a play lib bug, but welcome all ideas and suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer - it is a bug in the Android Google Maps library. The bug is exposed when you set padding on the MapView using [`setPadding`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#setPadding(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)). If you do not set any padding it behaves correctly.
Hopefully this will be useful to someone else who comes across this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Without code is quite impossible to help, but looking at your video I might guess...
If the Cross is not at the center, the LatLng of the Marker and LatLng of the camera are the same, then it is probably the anchor of the marker..

WHen you create a marker via MarkerOptions you can set the anchoring point of the marker:
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/MarkerOptions.html#anchor(float, float)

Given that marker, if you want it to be exactly centered you have to set the anchor as:

```
markeroptions.anchor(0.5f,0.5f);
```

It should work then